# Couldn't find a template file or inline render method for sub-component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-components

Getting this error:

```
ViewComponent::TemplateError in Welcome#show
Couldn't find a template file or inline render method for FaqComponent::QuestionComponent.
```

Kind of stuck forever with this issue, not sure how to resolve it. Trying to render a simple component using `view_component` gem.

```rb
# app/components/faq_component.rb

class FaqComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  renders_many :questions, "QuestionComponent"

  class QuestionComponent < ViewComponent::Base
    attr_reader :question

    def initialize(question: "")
      @question = question
    end
  end
end
```

Now, template file looks like:
file location: `app/components/faq_component/faq_component.html.erb`

```html
<%= content_tag :div, class: "c-faq", data: { controller: "faq" } do %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: "c-card" do %>
    <% questions.each do |q| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, class: "c-card__section" do %>
        <button class="c-faq__question" data-faq-target="question">
          <%= q.question %>
          <%= icon("arrow-expand", classes: "u-m-0", size: 12) %>
        </button>
        <div class="c-faq__answer">
          <%= q %> <!- IT'S GETTING ERROR HERE ->
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And finally trying to `render` here:

```html
    <div class="l-container u-mb-xxl u-xs-mb-l">
      <div class="l-row">
        <div class="l-col-xs-26 l-col-md-24 l-col-md-offset-1">
          <h3 class="u-mb-s">Common Questions</h3>
          <%= render(FaqComponent.new) do |faq| %>
            <% faq.question(question: "What is ViewComponent?") do %>
              <p>View component is a pain because it's not working or because I'm using it for the very first time!</p>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any help will highly appreciable! :bow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to define a template or `call method` for the `QuestionComponent` nested in the `FaqComponent`, that's the source of your errors.

That's why it fails at `<%= q %>`, which is trying to render the `QuestionComponent`. If you add a `app/components/faq_component/question_component.html.erb` file that would likely resolve the issue.

Maintainer replied [here](https://github.com/ViewComponent/view_component/discussions/1419#discussioncomment-3156899). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are inheriting class `QuestionComponent` from the wrong class, try inheriting it from `ViewComponent::Base`

```
# app/components/faq_component.rb

class FaqComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  renders_many :questions, "QuestionComponent"

  class QuestionComponent < ViewComponent::Base
    attr_reader :question

    def initialize(question: "")
      @question = question
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I'm already doing it `BaseComponent` is actually inherited from `ViewComponent::Base`. But still it's not working!